# Class 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting this error after added the   Intervention\Image\Facades\Image files to the vendor directory how can I fix it without using composer

Comment: Don't. Just use `composer`.

Comment: i can't use it in my capnel i dont know how to

Comment: Are you using `php artisan serve` or a proper web server? Did you clear cache etc.

Comment: i cleared config using this

Comment: Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:clear');

    // return what you want
});

Comment: can i do the same for serve

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you did this correctly,** add this to the providers section of your config/app.php file:

`Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,`

and add this: 
`'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,`

to the aliases section of the same file. make sure to copy the exact way i wrote it.

Comment: the same proplem

Comment: pls copy the error and post here, let me see exactly what it says.

Comment: Could you please use proper code formatting inside your answer in its current form it is hard to read and understand your answer.

Comment: FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider' not found

Comment: have you added this in your controller? use Image;

Comment: Have you followed [the documentation](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel) for adding Intervention Image to laravel?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't install package for image. 1st off all you install packege using this command.

" composer require intervention/image "